# Why all things doesn't work inside useEffect only once?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

My useSelector hook return null only inside useEffect when ı run other places it's working. For example:

```
// it's doesn't work.
const user = useSelector(selectUser);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user)
  }, []);
```

```
// it's work.
const user = useSelector(selectUser);
const exampleFunc = () => {
    console.log(user);
  }
  exampleFunc()
```

I am using google authentication. It returns null when the first login is made, but when I refresh the page, it returns user information not null. Why does the user information come in when the page is refreshed while returning null from the first entry? If I type Console.log("Hello world") the hook still doesn't work, but when I refresh the page it does.

```
// Redux
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  user: null,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state, action) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

```
// Original function
const user = useSelector(selectUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        dispatch(
          login({
            email: userAuth.email,
            uid: userAuth.uid,
            displayName: userAuth.displayName,
            photoUrl: userAuth.photoURL,
          })
        );
      } else if (!userAuth) {
        dispatch(logout());
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

**UPDATE:** I solved this problem. I changed useEffect function for as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const userInfo = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (userInfo) {
      dispatch(
        login({
          email: userInfo?.email,
          uid: userInfo?.uid,
          displayName: userInfo?.displayName,
          photoUrl: userInfo?.photoURL,
        })
      );
    } else if (!userInfo) {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `useEffect` you pass a dependencies array as the second argument

`useEffect(() => {}, [])`
When you pass no items into that array like above, the `useEffect` statement will only run on the first render, not after. It's basically telling react to only do this once - this is very similar to `componentDidMount`

`useEffect(() => {}, [dependency, secondDependency])`
When you pass dependencies to the array, the `useEffect` statement runs every time one of those dependencies changes. This is how you get your effect to rebuild on state changes.

See the docs for more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Okay, ı know this but when ı add my useSelector as a dependency, causing an infinite loop?

Comment: That seems like a separate question... If you update a piece of state inside of a `useEffect` statement and that same piece of state is also a dependency of that `useEffect` statement you will create an infinite loop. When you do that you update a piece of state, then run a function whenever that piece of state updates - that function updates the state again... infinite loop